# How to capture the rest of a sentence after one or two matching groups with regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

So i have two sentences that I'm working with and I'm interested in making specific capture groups based on the characters in a word. So i have these two spanish sentences:

1. Yo quiero irme de viaje.
2. Yo puedo caminar en la nieve.

The first capture group has to be one of the verbs ie. "quiero" and "puedo" so i do that with this regex `([PpDdQq].*o)`.
The second capture group has to be a word following directly after the verb, ending in "me" and I do that with `(\w*me)`. 
Now for the last capture group,it has to be all words and blankspaces following directly after the first capture group in the absence of a direct word ending in "-me" or all words and blankspaces following directly after the second capture group in the presence of a direct word ending in "-me", I used `(\w.+)` but it didn't work.

Could anybody help me figure out why? Thanks. Below is the full regex and [link](https://regex101.com/r/RkhgbB/1) to regex website containing the expression and examples to be matched:

`([PpDdQq].*o) |(\w*me)|(\w.+)`

Comment: Try this: `\b([PpDdQq]\w*o) (\w*me|.+)\b`

Comment: First you don't want \w because it will match numbers and underscore and it won't match latin letters. I imagine it depends on what version of python and your string encoding (yes python is a nightmare for things like this)

Comment: @anubhava that works but i forgot to add in the question that I wanted to capture the sentences after the "-me" ending word in another group. That is a third one. Could you help me figure that out?

Comment: @JohnsonDurant, could you please do add more samples of input and expected in your question to cover all possible cases for better understanding of your question please, thank you.

Comment: One possible solution: `([PpDdQq]\w*o) (\w*me) (.*)|([PpDdQq]\w*o) (.*)`. Note that the regex quantifiers are greedy and you want to put longest potential matches first when OR'ed together with `|`. I have removed the `g` and `m` options so the regex will be running line by line.

Comment: Note that the link to `regex101.com` is really useful but the input samples and expected output must all be contained inside your question so the question is self-contained, even if having the possibility to run them easily is a plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```py
\b([PpDdQq]\w*o)(?:\s+(\w*me))?\b(.*)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/MwptQe/2/).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [PpDdQq]                 any character of: 'P', 'p', 'D', 'd',
                             'Q', 'q'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    o                        'o'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0
                               or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      me                       'me'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
```